# What WheelEvent.deltaZ refers to?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mousewheel

While I was working on JavaScript events, I found a troubling element on the [wheel event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel): the [deltaZ member](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaZ).

I understood what was deltaX as horizontal scroll (available with some devices like a touchpad) and deltaY as vertical scroll (that is what any standard wheel do) but for deltaZ, the documentation says:

> The **WheelEvent.deltaZ** read-only property is a **double** representing the scroll amount along the z-axis

But still I cannot see what deltaZ refers to ? What kind of device can simulate a scroll on depth direction ? Even a joystick has only two axis, right ?

But as it is implemented on most web browsers, it has to have a meaning ? So which one ?

Comment: A '3d mouse' would send these messages. They would in that case be scrolling the depth value. Here's one of many available: http://www.leapaust.com.au/3dconnexion-mouse

Comment: What kind of movement do you do to scroll on Z-axis with this kind of mouse ? Is this handled by any game or any application ?

Comment: Well, you could make a 3d editor and use the z-axis scroll to move the camera along its look-at vector, while using the x and y ones to pan the camera. No idea if there are any html applications that utilize this particular property of the `WheelEvent`, sorry. :) (though, I'd assume there's _something_ )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a class of relatively new devices known as 3d-mice. These devices function like a standard 3 button mouse in addition to having extra capabilities.

An example of the input provided by such a device is shown below in an image from leapaust.com.au/3d-connexion-mouse.
[image]

Such input is most commonly made use of in 3d content-creation applications.